# Why is my database not updating?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

My problem is that when I am editing cells in the datagrid the database is not updating.
The code I used is below.

```
Public Class Form9
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM User_Account WHERE IsAdmin=False"
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCom)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form9_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Load

        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & _
            folderpath & "\TKIC\TKIC_Data_Storage.accdb'" & _
            ";Persist Security Info=True"
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        DataGridView1.Update()
        dt.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update the underlying `DataTable`. The `DataGridView.Update` causes the control to redraw the invalidated regions within its client area (basically repaints). The `dt.AcceptChanges()` only commits the changes in the DataTable not the database. The database has to be updated explicitly using the adapter and appropriate command texts. The `OleDbCommandBuilder` helps in forming the appropriate command texts.

Use the `OleDbDataAdapter` to update the database.

```
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
cb.QuotePrefix = "[";
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";
adapter.Update(datatable);
```