# How to save changes made to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I thought I knew how to do this, but when I am actually doing it, doesn't seem like I know how to do this.

What I am trying to achieve is display a filtered rows of table that is in dataset when search btn is clicked. Allow users to make changes on the datagridview or update selected rows with values provided on textbox on the update panel when Update btn is clicked. But I can't seem to achieve this.

```
 private void Display()
    {
        bindingSourceDisplay.DataSource=_dsNorthwind.Customers.Where(x=>!x.IsRegionNull()                         && !x.IsFaxNull()                                                                         && !x.IsPostalCodeNull()).Take(10);

        dgvSearchResult.DataSource = bindingSourceDisplay;
    }

 internal void UpdateSelectedRows(UpdateBtnClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //cannot do this because datagridviewselectedrow and customerrow are a type mismatch
        foreach (DS_Northwind.CustomersRow selectedRow in dgvSearchResult.SelectedRows)
        {
            selectedRow.Phone = e.PhoneNum;
            selectedRow.PostalCode = e.PostalCode;
        }
//how do I update each selected rows in datagridview? Can't do selectedRow.Cells["ColName"] either for some reason...
//if my dataset is connected to my database, isn't saving changes as simple as doing accept changes?
            _dsNorthwind.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is similar to the problem in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281938/why-is-my-database-not-updating See my answer to the question to get an idea to use the different DataAdapters

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a `DataAdapter` obejct.

Look at this post:

[Updating Database using Datagrid in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349535/updating-database-using-datagrid-in-c-sharp)